# Friend request send and Accept in Openfire

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I am using openfire server in android. Now I need to check how many users are online and who are they. My connection is OK. But I need to add or become a friend of those user. How to solve? Please anyone Help me.

**Output like as**

Called when the presence of a roster entry is changed

Name: esty

Status: unavailable

Called when the presence of a roster entry is changed

Name: roni

Status: unavailable

> Here Is My code:

```
public void OnlineUser()
{

    final Roster sroster = connection.getRoster();

    try {
        sroster.createEntry("esty", "test", null);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


     final Presence pr = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
     connection.sendPacket(pr);
 //  context.setConnection(Constants.connection);

    // final Roster roster =connection.getRoster();
     final Collection<RosterEntry> entries = sroster.getEntries();

    sroster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
         @Override
         public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
           //Called when the presence of a roster entry is changed
             for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

                if(pr.equals( presence)){
                    Log.v("roni", "Called when the presence of a roster entry is changed ");
                 Presence entryPresence = sroster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                 Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();       
                 uName =entry.getName().toString();
                 uStatus=type.toString();

                 Log.v("roni", "Name: " + entry.getName().toString());
                 Log.v("roni", "Status: " +type.toString());
                }



                 }
         }
         @Override
         public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
           // Called when a roster entries are updated.
             for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {


                    Log.v("roni", "Called when a roster entries are updated ");
                         Presence entryPresence = sroster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                         Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();       
                         uName =entry.getName().toString();
                         uStatus=type.toString();
                         Log.v("roni", "Namne: " + entry.getName().toString());
                         Log.v("roni", "Status: " +type.toString());

                 }
         }
         @Override
         public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
           // Called when a roster entries are removed.
             for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {


                    Log.v("roni", "Called when a roster entries are removed. ");
                         Presence entryPresence = sroster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                         Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();       
                         uName =entry.getName().toString();
                         uStatus=type.toString();
                         Log.v("roni", "Namne: " + entry.getName().toString());
                         Log.v("roni", "Status: " +type.toString());

                 }
         }
        @Override
         public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
           // Called when a roster entries are added.
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {


                Log.v("roni", " Called when a roster entries are added. ");
                     Presence entryPresence = sroster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                     Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();       
                     uName =entry.getName().toString();
                     uStatus=type.toString();
                     Log.v("roni", "Namne: " + entry.getName().toString());
                     Log.v("roni", "Status: " +type.toString());

             }
         }
        });



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want auto accept friend request then visit this link:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598454/check-online-offline-user-of-openfire-and-auto-accept-friend-request-using-andro/27635405#27635405)

hope it will solve your problem